# How to dynamically update MaterialUI DataGrid table in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

here's the general synopsis of what I'm trying to do:

- When the user clicks a checkbox in a row, that row is saved from being deleted (typically the user will click more than row).
- Every record without a checked checkbox is deleted once the user hits "purge records" button.

---

I got some general advice on how to do it, and I used the advice I was given accompanied by my own logic to come up with an implementation. The issue is that although I think my logic looks good and all my console.log statements looks good, the data in the  isn't updating. BTW, this is in a JSX file & not just a plain JS file.

I've been stuck on this for like a day now, and I'm genuinely stuck as to what my problem is/why this isn't working. Thank you for all your help and suggestions

---

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
const columns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70 },
  { field: "firstName", headerName: "First name", width: 130 },
  { field: "lastName", headerName: "Last name", width: 130 },
  { field: "age", headerName: "Age", type: "number", width: 90 },
  { field: "fullName", headerName: "Full name", description: "This column has a value getter and is not sortable.", 
    sortable: false,
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: (params) =>
      `${params.getValue("firstName") || ""} ${
        params.getValue("lastName") || ""
      }`
  },
  { field: "city", headerName: "City", width: 100 },
  { field: "state", headerName: "State", width: 100 }
];

var data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    lastName: "Snow",
    firstName: "Jon",
    age: 35,
    city: "Milwaukee",
    state: "Wisconsin"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    lastName: "Lannister",
    firstName: "Cersei",
    age: 42,
    city: "Dubuque",
    state: "Iowa"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    lastName: "Lannister",
    firstName: "Jaime",
    age: 45,
    city: "Appleton",
    state: "Wisconsin"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    lastName: "Stark",
    firstName: "Arya",
    age: 16,
    city: "Madison",
    state: "Wisconsin"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    lastName: "Targaryenmnsdlfbsjbgjksbgksbfksfgbk",
    firstName: "Daenerys",
    age: null,
    city: "Green Bay",
    state: "Wisconsin"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    lastName: "Melisandre",
    firstName: null,
    age: 150,
    city: "San Antonio",
    state: "Texas"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    lastName: "Clifford",
    firstName: "Ferrara",
    age: 44,
    city: "Dallas",
    state: "Texas"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    lastName: "Frances",
    firstName: "Rossini",
    age: 36,
    city: "Brooklyn",
    state: "New York"
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    lastName: "Roxie",
    firstName: "Harvey",
    age: 65,
    city: "Toledo",
    state: "Ohio"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    lastName: "Larry",
    firstName: "King",
    age: 105,
    city: "Chicago",
    state: "Illiniois"
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    lastName: "Snow",
    firstName: "Jon",
    age: 35,
    city: "Milwaukee",
    state: "Wisconsin"
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    lastName: "Lannister",
    firstName: "Cersei",
    age: 42,
    city: "Dubuque",
    state: "Iowa"
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    lastName: "Lannister",
    firstName: "Jaime",
    age: 45,
    city: "Appleton",
    state: "Wisconsin"
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    lastName: "Stark",
    firstName: "Arya",
    age: 16,
    city: "Madison",
    state: "Wisconsin"
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    lastName: "Targaryenmnsdlfbsjbgjksbgksbfksfgbk",
    firstName: "Daenerys",
    age: null,
    city: "Green Bay",
    state: "Wisconsin"
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    lastName: "Melisandre",
    firstName: null,
    age: 150,
    city: "San Antonio",
    state: "Texas"
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    lastName: "Clifford",
    firstName: "Ferrara",
    age: 44,
    city: "Dallas",
    state: "Texas"
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    lastName: "Frances",
    firstName: "Rossini",
    age: 36,
    city: "Brooklyn",
    state: "New York"
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    lastName: "Roxie",
    firstName: "Harvey",
    age: 65,
    city: "Toledo",
    state: "Ohio"
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    lastName: "Larry",
    firstName: "King",
    age: 105,
    city: "Chicago",
    state: "Illiniois"
  }
];

var rowsToKeep = [];
var rowsToBeDeleted = [];

class ElgibleContracts extends Component {
  //const [rows, setRows] = useState(data);
  //const [deletedRows, setDeletedRows] = useState([]);

  /*
  * It's assumed that the user will want to delete all the rows,
  * but there will be scenarios when that's not the case.
  */
  setRowsToBeDeleted = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      rowsToBeDeleted.push(data[i].id);
    }
    rowsToBeDeleted = [...new Set(rowsToBeDeleted)]; //Did this because clicking the button twice will make doubles appear for each row
    
  };

  /*
   * This method fires off when the checkbox is clicked for a given row.
  */
  handleRowSelection = (e) => {
    // remove it if it's already present - this means the user unchecked it
    if (rowsToKeep.includes(e.data.id)){
      for(var i = 0; i < rowsToKeep.length; i++){ 
        if (rowsToKeep[i] === e.data.id){ 
          rowsToKeep.splice(i, 1); 
        }
      }
    } else {
      // user clicked it - add it to the list of rows to keep.
      rowsToKeep.push(e.data.id);
    }

    this.setRowsToBeDeleted();
    console.log("Rows to Keep: " + rowsToKeep);
    //setDeletedRows([...deletedRows, ...rows.filter((r) => r.id === e.data.id)]);
    //console.log("All rows: " + rows);
  };

  /*
  * This method updates the data that's to be displayed.
  */
  handlePurge = () => {
    // Check to see what rows are to be deleted and which ones aren't.
    for (var j = 0; j < rowsToKeep.length; j++){
      if (rowsToBeDeleted.includes(rowsToKeep[j])){
        // delete it from 'rows to be deleted' array
        console.log("Found:" + rowsToKeep[j]);
        while(rowsToBeDeleted.indexOf(rowsToKeep[j]) !== -1) {
          rowsToBeDeleted.splice(rowsToBeDeleted.indexOf(rowsToKeep[j]), 1)
        }
      } else {
        // do nothing
      }
    } 

    // remove it from the data set. Just used ID of 1 in this case to test whether or not it would work
    data = data.filter(function(item) { 
      return item.id !== 1;  
    });
    
    console.log("Rows to Delete: " + rowsToBeDeleted);
    console.log("Here are deleted items",rowsToBeDeleted);
  };

  render(){
    return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <h1 style={{ fontFamily: "Stone" }}>Elgible Contracts</h1>
      <span className="horizontal-line" />
      <div className="centerDiv" style={{ height: 380, width: 950 }}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={data}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={10}
          checkboxSelection
          onRowSelected={this.handleRowSelection}
        />
      </div>
      <br />
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" startIcon={<DeleteIcon />} style={{textTransform: "none"}} onClick={this.handlePurge}>
        Purge Records
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
}

export default ElgibleContracts;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are not keeping the state of your data. I see you've attempted to use hooks - these will not work inside a class component so just use the state class property

```
class ElgibleContracts extends Component {
  //const [rows, setRows] = useState(data); <-- this will not work in class component
  //const [deletedRows, setDeletedRows] = useState([]); <-- this will not work in class component

  state = {
    data: data // use state class property instead
  };
```

Inside your `handlePurge` method, this is where you set the new state for the filtered data

```
let data_to_be_kept = this.state.data.filter(function (item) {
  return rowsToBeDeleted.includes(item.id) === false;
});

this.setState({
  data: data_to_be_kept
});
```

Finally, in your `DataGrid`, the value of `prop` `rows` should be assigned the value of the `state` `data`

```
<DataGrid
  rows={this.state.data}
  columns={columns}
  pageSize={10}
  checkboxSelection
  onRowSelected={this.handleRowSelection}
/>
```

[image: Edit hopeful-bouman-6s9mo]

Comment: I'm getting same error with hooks. Do you have any idea if it support it?

Comment: regardless of class or function (i.e., hooks) it should work. to answer your question, yes -  MUI DataGrid supports hooks. the general idea of how to solve this is to simply have the prop `rows` to have a dynamic value which is bound to a `state`. when the state updates, the `DataGrid` updates

Comment: Thanks. I created simple example with useState for rows, but I'm facing super slow performance and data rendring. Currently I try to understand if it is related to a mismatch versions with react or react-dom

Comment: if you are dealing with big data, i suggest you look into virtualized tables. here is an example from mui docs: https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#virtualized-table

Comment: Thanks for the info, my example uses small data, I fixed the issue by updating packages to "@material-ui/data-grid": "4.0.0-alpha.10", "@material-ui/core": "4.11.1", "react": "^17.0.1".

Comment: Is the logic backwards? Shouldn't "purge" function delete the selected rows? It is actually keeping the selected.