# Material-UI DataGrid Component Refresh with new State Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

Good morning,

We are using Material-UI to create a DataGrid table filled with users and want to be able to delete selected entries (checkbox) using a button.

Clicking the button updates the state of our object (removing the expected rows) and the DataGrid element of Material-UI takes as parameter `this.state.rows` (as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64269302/how-to-dynamically-update-materialui-datagrid-table-in-react-js) Stack Overflow).

The logs shown below prove that the state element is indeed updated following the `setState()` call (blue rectangle) which re-renders the DataGrid Component (red rectangle). However nothing changes visually :(

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6y7z.jpg)

The code is shown below:

```
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';
import * as React from 'react';

import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';

class EmployeeGrid extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
        this.hrefs = {}
        this.columns = [
            { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
            { field: 'firstName', headerName: 'First name', width: 130 },
            { field: 'lastName', headerName: 'Last name', width: 130 },
            { field: 'description', headerName: 'Description', width: 200 }
        ];
        
        let employeeList = [];
        let id = 1;
        for (const employee of this.props.employees) {
            this.hrefs[id] = employee.url;
            employeeList.push({
                id: id,
                firstName: employee.entity.firstName,
                lastName: employee.entity.lastName,
                description: employee.entity.description
            });
            id++;
        }
        console.log(this.hrefs)
        console.log(employeeList)
        this.state={rows: employeeList, //populate initial state with all employees from database
                    selected: [],
                    nbRender: 1}
        console.log(this.state.rows);
    }

    handleDelete() {
        for (let id of this.state.selected) {
            this.state.rows.splice(id - 1, 1); //delete rows that were selected
            this.props.onDelete(this.hrefs[id]); //delete from database
        }
        this.setState({rows: this.state.rows, selected: [], nbRender: 2}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.rows) //checks state is indeed updated
        });
        console.log(this.state.rows);
    }

    render() {
        console.log("In render of EmployeeGrid");
        console.log(this.state.rows)
        return (
            <div>
                <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
                    <DataGrid rows={this.state.rows} //populate grid with state.rows
                                columns={this.columns}
                                pageSize={this.props.pageSize}
                                checkboxSelection 
                                onSelectionChange={(newSelection) => {
                                    this.setState({selected: newSelection.rowIds})
                                }}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Button variant="contained"
                            color="secondary"
                            startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
                            onClick={this.handleDelete}>
                                Delete
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>   
        )
    }
}

export default EmployeeGrid;
```

**EDIT 1**

After more analysis, we found that the reason why the log shows 4 rows in the console logs is because we updated the state inplace at line:

```
this.state.rows.splice(id - 1, 1); //delete rows that were selected
```

We now notice that the following line is never called which in turn does not re-render the page update.

```
 this.setState({rows: this.state.rows, selected: [], nbRender: 2}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.rows) //checks state is indeed updated
        });
```

Once again any ideas on why this could arise would be much appreciated!

Cheers and keep safe

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you mutate state here

```
this.state.rows.splice(id - 1, 1)
```

Try this one

```
handleDelete() {
    for (let id of this.state.selected) {
        this.props.onDelete(this.hrefs[id]); //delete from database
    }
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      rows: prevState.rows.filter((row) => !prevState.selected.includes(row.id)),
      selected: [], 
      nbRender: 2
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sergey for your reply. We tried your solution but this did not change what we found i.e. this.setState is never called and the state is never updated as shown in our Edit 1 above in the original post.